# Rails 3.1 Geocoding not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I have a Rink model with this code:

```
geocoded_by :full_street_address
after_validation :geocode

...

def full_street_address
  [address, city, 'Ontario', 'Canada'].compact.join(', ')
end
```

And then in db/seeds.rb I have something in this format:

```
Rink.create([
{
  name: 'Alexander Park',
  address: '259 Whitney Ave.',
  city: 'Hamilton',
  rink_type: 'outdoor',
  phone: '9055463747'
}, .... ])
```

When I run rake db:seed on my local machine all the Rink objects are created and properly geocoded.  But when I push to Heroku and run the same command (heroku run rake db:seed) some seemingly random subset of the Rink objects are not properly geocoded and have null values for latitude and longitude.  Running the db:seed command on Heroku multiple times changes the set of Rink objects not properly geocoded.  Any thoughts?

Comment: How big is the attribute array you're using to seed?

Answer (score 2):

I would put an hourly cron in your app (or a daily cron) like so:

```
Rink.not_geocoded.find_each do |rink|
  rink.geocode
end
```

What's probably happening is that your app is using the same IP address as other Heroku applications to make the Geocoder API request, and the default API (google) is rate limiting based on IP address to 2500 requests per day.

If you sign up for an API key then you should be able to make your requests (within 2500 /day) and have your OWN limit, not shared with other apps.

Comment: Google geocoding is tied to an ip address, so even if you use an api key, you are still limited to the request limit on shared IP address.